# Spring boot DB health check fails

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I looked up for a while before asking this question. The default health check for the DB fails with invalid sql type. Has anyone seen this before?

```
{
status: "DOWN",
db: {
status: "DOWN",
dataSource1: {
status: "DOWN",
database: "Oracle",
error: "org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: StatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL ["SELECT 1 from dual"]; SQL state [99999]; error code [17439]; Invalid SQL type: sqlKind = 0; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Invalid SQL type: sqlKind = 0"
},
dataSource: {
status: "DOWN",
database: "Oracle",
error: "org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: StatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL ["SELECT 1 from dual"]; SQL state [99999]; error code [17439]; Invalid SQL type: sqlKind = 0; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Invalid SQL type: sqlKind = 0"
}
}
}
```

Comment: Could you show your procedure and your code?

Comment: These are the default health indicators. Generally it runs select 1 from dual query. Reference - http://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-actuators